# Celery task not running and stuck in PENDING

Tags: python, docker, flask, rabbitmq, celery

I'm following one of the various tutorials out on the internet and set up a Flask/RabbitMQ/Celery app using Docker/Docker Compose. The containers all appear to run successfully but when I hit the endpoint, the app stalls. The task appears to be stuck in `PENDING` and never actually completes. There are no errors in the Docker output, so I'm really confused why this isn't working. The only output I see when I hit my endpoint is this:

```
rabbit_1    | 2021-05-13 01:38:07.942 [info] <0.760.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.760.0> (172.19.0.4:45414 -> 172.19.0.2:5672)
rabbit_1    | 2021-05-13 01:38:07.943 [info] <0.760.0> connection <0.760.0> (172.19.0.4:45414 -> 172.19.0.2:5672): user 'rabbitmq' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
rabbit_1    | 2021-05-13 01:38:07.952 [info] <0.776.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.776.0> (172.19.0.4:45416 -> 172.19.0.2:5672)
rabbit_1    | 2021-05-13 01:38:07.953 [info] <0.776.0> connection <0.776.0> (172.19.0.4:45416 -> 172.19.0.2:5672): user 'rabbitmq' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
```

I'm really not sure what I am doing wrong as the documentation hasn't been much help.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD ["app.py","--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Flask `app.py`

```
from workerA import add_nums
from flask import (
   Flask,
   request,
   jsonify,
)
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/add")
def add():
    first_num = request.args.get('f')
    second_num = request.args.get('s')
    result = add_nums.delay(first_num, second_num)
    return jsonify({'result': result.get()}), 200



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Celery `workerA.py`

```
from celery import Celery
# Celery configuration
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://rabbitmq:rabbitmq@rabbit:5672/'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'
# Initialize Celery
celery = Celery('workerA', broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL, backend=CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND)


@celery.task()
def add_nums(a, b):
   return a + b
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
    volumes:
      - .:/app
  rabbit:
    hostname: rabbit
    image: rabbitmq:management
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rabbitmq
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5673:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
  worker_1:
    build:
      context: .
    hostname: worker_1
    entrypoint: celery
    command: -A workerA worker --loglevel=info -Q workerA
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - rabbit
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after much research I determined that the issue was the queue name for the task. Celery was using the default name for the queue and it was causing some problems. I adjusted my decorated like so:

```
@celery.task(queue='workerA')
def add_nums(a, b):
   return a + b
```

And now it works!